# SlideView panel - don't know how to reference

Tags: windows-phone-8

After doing months of Android, I'm picking up Windows Phone again.
I wanted to install the nuget package for the SlideView control:

> https://slideview.codeplex.com/

I installed it, but I have no idea how to reference it in XAML.
In the sample it uses the control namespace, but I don't have it,
so I should define it, but I don't know how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this on the top of your xaml page `<phone:PhoneApplicationPage>` tag.

```
 xmlns:library="clr-namespace:SlidingPanel.Library;assembly=SlidingPanel.Library"
```

Then you could use that reference below anywhere to access all the properties of `SlidePanel`.

Refer [this](https://slideview.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Trunk/SlidingPanel/SlideView.Sample.WP8/Shell.xaml) for more:

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot, with this entry I could finally start using it:  xmlns:library="clr-namespace:SlideView.Library;assembly=SlideView.Library"